# can't delete a file due to permissions, both file and parent dir are 775

Tags: permissions

I am fairly green on Linux.  I have a dir called PHP that has permissions of `775` with owner/group of `caddy:caddy` and all files and subdirectories are exactly the same, `775` and `caddy:caddy`.  Now I am signed in as `jack` who has `caddy` as a secondary group, if that matters at all. I am inside the PHP folder and trying to delete a file. When I type `rm filename` it asks `rm: remove write-protected regular file 'filename'`?  I type `y` and it says `cannot remove filename: Permission denied`. If I `sudo`, it works fine. The reason I would like to do this without `sudo`, is I am trying to remove a bunch of different files while signed in as that user in Filezilla.

Some more details to clear up confusion. The PC I am trying to delete the files from is running Ubuntu 21.10. I am on a Windows 10 PC using bash console to ssh in as `jack` and delete a file in that PHP folder. That is when it says `cannot remove filename: Permission denied`.

I tried SSHFS, very cool!  Did not know about that.  I can't figure out how to navigate up out of the user home directory though.

`id` command prints the following:
`uid=1001(jack) gid=1001(jack) groups=1001(jack),27(sudo)`

I do not see any pluses after typing ls -l when in PHP's parent folder.

`groups jack` prints out `jack : jack sudo caddy`

Comment: Don't use FTP any more., sshfs is a reasonable replacement. You're probably not signed on as jack, FTP servers tend to have private user databases You don't say what FTP server implementation you're using so it's hard to tell, but if jack as write access and you signed on as jack you're using one of those, since you're getting the "remove write-protected regular file" prompt: the actual host system doesn't think you're "jack".

Comment: Does the `id` command confirm processes in the login session have the `caddy` supplementary gid? Does the directory have the `t` bit set? Are there any ACLs on the directory (a `+` in the `ls -l` output often indicates that)? What's the OS? You only mentioned Linux which is just the kernel.  FileZilla supports a number of protocols. Which one would you be using?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I added more details in my post.

Comment: With sshfs you can't, you should mount the root if you want full filesystem access. If `id` says you're jack and ls -l says it's owned by jack, and you're still getting the read-only permissions, . . . maybe the filesystem's mounted readonly?

Comment: It is owned by caddy, which jack is a member of.

Comment: I tried to mount the root with `/~` after the server when mapping the network drive and that failed.

Comment: Got it!  Had to add `/../..` after the host name.  And I am able to successfully delete the file from in there!  Feel free to add that as an answer if you'd like.  Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand your setup and your solution well enough to be sure of a correct answer, sshfs shouldn't require a `/../..` path to mount the filesystem root and I don't see where filezilla provides general command access so I don't see how or where you were issuing that `id` command . . . yeah. I'm not sure exactly how. I helped, but I'm glad you got it working.

Comment: Oh sorry, wherever I was running the commands, I was doing it from a bash console.  By default when I mapped my drive to the SSHFS server, it was only showing the home folder for the user 'jack' and I had no way to traverse up two folders to get to root.  So that is what the `/../..` allowed me to do.  Not sure why, but that was required to mount the filesystem root for me.